# Version 2.78, gtx 1080, Cycles Render, Rendered Viewport, Black Screen

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

My issue is when using Blender 2.78, my screen will flicker and go black in portions, whenever I enter rendered in the viewport (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>). This happens whether blender is the only application running or not, but if I have a video playing on the other monitor (my Blender course), the web page will often freeze, reload, or otherwise be wonky.

I am using an NVidia GTX 1080 (I believe it has 8 GB of memory), windows 10 64 bit, 16 GB of memory, and an Intel 6700k processor. I'm rendering with GPU compute. I also have a GSync monitor with GSync running.

The problem happens often, but not all of the time. To fix it, I have to move the mouse around the screen, or move the window itself.

Since pascal GPU compatibility was just recently added for cycles render, I thought maybe it could be a bug with the software, but I don't see anyone having a similar issue.

Below are images of the problem (working fine, black screen effect):

[image: Blender Normal]

[image: Blender Messed Up]

Comment: May be an issue with GSync, have you tried turning it off? May be a driver issue, overheating, a faulty GPU memory or  simply a Blender bug, Hard to tell

Comment: With GSync on or off, and with the new driver I just installed, the issue persists. I'm not really sure how to deal with, or even check my GPU memory.

Comment: Page freezing and weird behavior for other opened applications is expected while GPU rendering though, since the device is busy processing the scene it can't keep up with much more heavy stuff in parallel.

Comment: Also, Blender frequently crashes in cycles render using GPU compute. I tried running from command prompt with -d, but there was no message of why it crashed, and I saw no temp file for the crash.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because last night I encountered this as well. I'm on GTX 1060 running Blender 2.78. That was the first time I'd seen it happen over the past two weeks (I've only been using Blender for 2 weeks now). Except for GPU, your system sounds very similar to mine, and I'm seeing it as well.

Comment: Also, I switched to a GTX Titan (Pascal, so it's the same 10 series), and the issue persists, including the crashes.